# How do I run a process that wants to become root from a systemd service which is a regular user?

Tags: systemd, services, setuid, capabilities

I have a service that I start using systemd. The service user and group are changed to a non-privileged user.

```
[Service]
...
User=regular_user
Group=regular_user
...
```

At some point the service needs to start another process, which is expected to become root. That other process has its 's' bit set and it uses `setuid()` to become root.

The process works just fine if I start it. However, somehow, when the service tries to start it, the `setuid()` function returns with an error:

> Operation not permitted.

I've seen some options about capabilities, but I have no clue whether those are what needs to be used to keep the `setuid()` capability working in my service. I tried a few things and none helped so far.

For example, I tried that:

```
AmbientCapabilities=CAP_SETGID CAP_SETUID
SecureBits=keep-caps
```

And although the process does not seem to generate an error anymore, it still does not do what it is supposed to do (again, if I run that process in my console, it works just fine!)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I actually found the [NoNewPrivileges=](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#NoNewPrivileges=) option that allows my process children to use the `setuid()`.

From what they are saying, it is certainly not an option one should lightly choose to use. However, the default is: do not allow the `setuid()` feature. (what they mean by *«elevate privileges»*.)

What worked for me was to do this:

```
NoNewPrivileges=false
```

Note that the documentation does not clearly say that the default for this option is true on Ubuntu 16.04. This may vary depending on the OS.

Comment: On which OS and version was the default tested to be set to true?

Comment: @MarkStosberg, I added the OS info in the answer.

Comment: After I filled a bug report, the default value for this is now documented. It defaults to `false` for system services, but can be defaulted to true for user-managed services if certain other directives are set. Details are here: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/commit/74388c2d11acd9b638e33e09c7a99a9bc2c6292b

Comment: @MarkStosberg, thank you for fixing the docs. That's a big job for such a large project.